# Conditional binomials

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, conditional-probability

I'm trying to proof this,
If X ~ B(n, p) and, conditional on X, Y ~ B(X, q), then Y is a simple binomial variable with distribution Y ~ B(n, pq) .
Can someone show me how or link some reference.

Comment: Several approaches lead to this result rather directly. Which ones did you try?

Comment: Or you can try to prove this yourself. I think someone asked this same question not long ago.

Comment: I think moment generating function or probability generating function is a quick and easy way, though you can also do this straight from definition.

Comment: This should be re-opened.  It's a reference request, not a question about how to do a math problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me no particular reference comes to mind immediately.  Let's try it:
$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y=y) & = \mathbb E(\Pr(Y=y\mid X)) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{x=0}^n \Pr(Y=y\mid X=x)\Pr(X=x) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{x=0}^n \binom x y q^y(1-q)^{x-y} \binom n x p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{x=y}^n\cdots\cdots\text{ditto}\cdots\cdots \qquad(\text{discarding the zero terms}) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{w=0}^{n-y} \binom{w+y}{y} q^y (1-q)^{w} \binom{n}{w+y} p^{w+y}(1-p)^{n-y-w} \\[10pt]
& = (pq)^y \sum_{w=0}^{n-y} \binom{n}{w+y} \binom{w+y}{w} ((1-q)p)^w (1-p)^{(n-y)-w} \\[10pt]
& = (pq)^y \binom{n}{y} \sum_{w=0}^{n-y} \binom{n-y}{w} ((1-q)p)^w (1-p)^{(n-y)-w} \text{ (see comment below)} \\[10pt]
& \dots\text{and now apply the binomial theorem in a routine way:} \\[10pt]
& = \binom{n}{y} (pq)^y \Big( (1-q)p + 1-p \Big)^{n-y} \\[10pt]
& \dots\text{then some simple algebraic simplifications:} \\[10pt]
& = \binom{n}{y} (pq)^y  (1-pq)^{n-y},
\end{align}
$$
as predicted.

**Comment:** The problem now is why is it true that
$$
\binom{n}{w+y} \binom{w+y}{w} = \binom{n}{y} \binom{n-y}{w}.
$$
A bijective argument about choosing two subcommittees will do that.

Comment: Completing previous comment: \begin{align} {n \choose w+y}{w+y \choose w} &= \frac{n!}{(n-w-y)!w!y} \\ &= \frac{n!(n-y)!}{((n-y)-w)!w!y!(n-y)!} \\ &= {n \choose y}{n-y \choose w}
\end{align}

Comment: @user161271 : It's not clear which "previous comment" this "complete[s]", but what you wrote is certainly not an argument about choosing two subcommittees.